# Adding a column to an existing module from my custom module

Tags: orchardcms

I've tried to do this and have been unsuccessful.

Is it possible from within my custom module to have a migration to add a column to an existing Orchard module outside of my module?  (For instance, trying to add a column named "UseFluidContainer" to a widget part.

Thanks!

Edit:

I have tried the following in a migration file of the module I've created but the column is not added:

```
public int Create() {
        SchemaBuilder.AlterTable(typeof(WidgetPartRecord).Name, table => table
            .AddColumn<bool>("UseFluidLayout", c => c.WithDefault(false)));

        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Usually for these kinds of questions, users will post sample code they are working with to provide scope and context.  If you would do that, it would be much easier to provide help.

Comment: I'd like to point out that you probably shouldn't do that: if you want to add data to a type, the proper way to do it is to add your own part or field. From your code sample, it seems like you are modifying the Widget module's schema, which is a big no-no.
The simplest is almost certainly to add a Boolean field instead, which doesn't require a schema change at all.